# vagrant 1.7.2 + puppet 4.2 provisioning not working

Tags: vagrant, puppet, provisioning

Trying to spin-up a VM using vagrant and puppet 4.2. The puppent configuration in the Vagrantfile is:

```
config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.options = ['--verbose --debug']
    puppet.environment_path = "../puppet/environments"
    puppet.environment = "testenv"
end
```

as per Vagrant [documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html) (search for environments section)

After running `vagrant up` I get the following error message:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

puppet provisioner:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: environment, environment_path
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe puppet 4 support was coming from 1.7.3 - you should upgrade vagrant to this version or even 1.7.4

issue was https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/5601
and  [vagrant changelog](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: vagrant upgrade to latest version solved the issue! thanks :)